# How do I find complex eigenvectors if I know the complex eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Assume that we know the complex eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. Is there a way for us to find the complex eigenvectors by finding the nullspace?

$$(A-\lambda_i I)W_i = 0$$

Where $W_i$ is the complex eigenvectors.
I don't want to use SVD, because I don't have a SVD solver that can handle imaginary numbers. I'm running everything in C code by the way!

Yes! I have searched for C-code about eigenvectors, but it seems only be for symmetrical matrices.

Notice that this question is about non-symmetrical matrices.

Comment: What is $ j_i $?

Comment: It's the imaginary eigenvector. Sorry

Comment: @copper.hat $r_i$ real eigenvalues, $j_i$ imaginary eigenvectors.

Comment: @copper.hat Changed now

Comment: @copper.hat Yes. Update the page.

Comment: So, the real question is how to find the null space of a complex matrix without doing complex arithmetic?

Comment: @copper.hat Hmm, yes that can be a way to do that.

Comment: Do you have access to a QR factorisation routine? (Note, usually the eigenvectors are computed at the same time as eigenvalues.)

Comment: @copper.hat Yes. But only for real numbers.

Comment: @copper.hat This is what I have https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/tree/master/src/CControl/Sources/LinearAlgebra

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to do. There are lots of (complex) SVD, QR routines out there. If this is for experimentation you could use Gram Schmidt to estimate the null space. The numerical properties are not as nice as QR but it is easy to code. You will need complex arithmetic but that is straightforward to implement.

Comment: @copper.hat It's super clear. I want to find the complex eigenvectors. I don't have complex SVD or QR routine. Sorry. Not using BLAS. Do you think I can use gaussian to solve $(A-\lambda I)W = 0$?

Comment: If I were doing it I would use Gram Schmidt.

Comment: @copper.hat Not house holder?

Comment: Honestly I can't tell if you are messing with me or not. If you are willing to do Householder then just code up a (complex) QR. I really am not sure what you are looking for. Why won't you code up an algorithm to do complex arithmetic?

Comment: @copper.hat I can do that. I can borrow my QR.c function and just use complex numbers insead of real ones. But isin't there an easier way? I already know my complex eigenvalues.